# Segmentation fault error ( cs50 problemset week2)

Tags: c, cs50

I try to get the user to type a specific command line to execute my program, but ./caesar leads to segmentation fault, while no return statement is included. With return statement, everything works perfectly.
Can someone explain to me why that's the case and if there is another solution to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

if(argc != 2)
{
  printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n"); 
  //return 1; 
}

for(int i = 0, p = strlen(argv[1]); i < p; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(argv[1][i]))
    {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");   
    
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `return 1;` statement that you commented out or about an extra `return 0;` at the end of the function? A missing return at the end does not cause a segfault and is added implicitely for C99 and later.

Comment: So just include the `return` statement... The implicit return is just a crutch, but there's no need to be lazy and miss it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` exits your function early, so the code afterwards doesn't get run. If you don't provide an argument, `argc` won't be 2, and `argv[1]` wouldn't be a valid string. With a `return`, then usage message prints and then the return stops execution there, so you don't try to call `strlen(argv[1])`, which will segfault.

Without the return, you print the usage message, but the code keeps running, and you call `strlen(argv[1])`, which will cause a segfault.